# If function $u$, is $ C^1$ function on two almost disjoint compact sets, then is $u \in W^{1,\infty}$ of union of two sets?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let B denote the open unit ball in $R^n$, $B_+ = \{x \in B : x_n > 0\}$ and 
$B_- = \{x \in B : x_n < 0\}$. Also 
Suppose u ∈ $C^1(\overline B_+)\bigcap C^1(\overline B_-)$.

I was trying to figure out is it true that u ∈ $W^{1,∞}(B)$? Is there any counterexample? If yes, then what kind of modification or addition of the assumptions is needed to make the statement correct?

Any kind of help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true in general. Recall that $u\in W^{1,\infty}(B)$ implies that $u$ is Lipschitz continuous. We define $u\equiv 1$ on $B_+$ and $u\equiv -1$ on $B_-$, then $u$ is not Lipschitz continuous. I think if your impose the condition that $u$ is continuous on $\{x\in B:\,x_n=0\}$, then it is true.

Comment: What you said about continuity condition is correct.